# How to interrupt in microcontroller?

Tags: microcontroller, pic, microchip

I need your help in my graduation project
 It is a smart home project in which i am using two PIC micro-controllers PIC16f877A for LCD & Keypad which is a way of devices control connected to the main micro PIC18f4550 i have problems in main micro code 
could you help me please

I am trying to achieve multi way home automation with some security like fire system and recording camera .
one micro for lcd and keypad connection.
another to handle interrupts coming from different ways of devices control like keypad , GSM messages serially connected , C# windows application USB connected and remote.

[my code link here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B7jw0zvYc42cdmJPbGRzOWQ0MW8&authuser=0)

Comment: Did you have a specific question ?

Comment: is my interrupt code is right ?

Comment: You need an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) really - probably no one has time to look at all that code in detail.

Comment: The interrupt enable bits should be set last after the rest of the interrupt bits. It's not considered good practice to have large and slow interrupt routines, you have delays of seconds in there and call some big functions. Instead, the interrupt routine should just set flags which are picked up in the main loop and that calls the larger routines. You may need to use a queue for anything that is sent serially. TRISB = 1 only sets RB0 to be input, I think you mean TRISB = 0xFF. Make sure all pins are set to digital and not analogue inputs (if they can be analogue, it is the default).

Comment: I will consider what you said in my code and try again ,thanks very much